# Calculate the modular inverse of $2a$ given that of $a$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

My problem is that I have to calculate some modular inverses of numbers that are related by multiplying by $2$, that is:

Given $a$ and $x$ so that $ax\equiv1\mod n$ ($n$ being an odd number) I need to calculate $x'$ so that $2ax'\equiv 1 \mod n$

By some testing I have found that the formula:
$$x' = x + \frac{n-x}{2}$$
seem to apply.

Is this formula correct, or is it just that for the particular cases that I have tried apply? And if it is incorrect, is there a general formula for solving my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's correct. $x'=(n+x)/2$, $2ax'=a(n+x)=ax+nx\equiv ax\equiv 1\pmod n$

Comment: Ah, nice, I had only tried it for a couple of cases and found it valid, thanks. If you want, you can write it as a full answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has $(ab)^{-1}= a^{-1}b^{-1}$ (assuming all inverses exist). 
Thus with $b=2$ and  noting $2^{-1}= (n+1)/2$, you get 
$$x (n+1)/2 $$
as the inverse. 
This is congruent to what you have, as $x$ must be odd and thus $(x-1)n/2 =0$.